# Is `pam_limits.so` used like a command?

Tags: kernel-modules, pam

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_limits.8.html

> SYNOPSIS         top
>
> ```
>    pam_limits.so [conf=/path/to/limits.conf] [debug] [set_all]
>                  [utmp_early] [noaudit]
> ```

Does the synopsis suggest that `pam_limits.so` is used like a command name?

Or is `pam_limits.so` a module, and can it be loaded and unloaded just like any other module?

Thanks.

Comment: The modules will be loaded by various services as dictated by the entries in the files held in /etc/pam.d

Comment: what does its SYNOPSIS mean? Does that mean the command line syntax?

Answer (score 5):

No, the `pam_*.so` modules are shared libraries:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security# file pam_limits.so 
pam_limits.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=..., stripped
```

And the ones on my Ubuntu system don't even have the `x` bits set. Since they're technically ELF files, you can *try to* run them, but it doesn't really work:

```
/tmp$ chmod +x pam_limits.so 
/tmp$ ./pam_limits.so 
Segmentation fault
```

They're loaded by the PAM libraries, based on the configuration in `/etc/pam.d/`. The modules can be given arguments there, e.g.:

```
session       required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale
```

The man page just documents the options that can be used here.